# Visual Studio 2008 trial expired, how to insert serial?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2008, serial

[image: This message occurred after trying to open vb 2008]

How to enter serial to upgrade to professional?
Surely I have valid cd key on my case.
When I clicked that Upgrade button then just following [This MS site](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=34249&clcid=%25d)

It didn't ask cd key when I installing it.

Comment: I might be off, but I think you'll have to reinstall the actual full product rather than the "Trial Edition". However, is there any specific reason you're reinstalling VS2008? Can't you just use VS2017 Community Edition due to revenue or company size?

Comment: I've specific reason I'm reinstalling VS2008.